# Suppose that for the second round (Eighth final) of the Soccer World Cup we have the following configuration:

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many different ways can the 14 empty squares in the above configuration be filled? Remember that starting from the second round, each match must have a winner (no ties). The winner of a match advances to the next round and the loser is eliminated.

My attempt: first of all, we can see that in total 15 matches will be played. On the left side, for the eighth final there are $2^4= 16$ chances to play all the games, in the quarterfinals there are $2^2= 4$ chances, in the semifinals there are only $2$ chances. Therefore there are $16+4+2=22$ possibilities of play on the left side. On the right hand side it is similar, therefore there are $44$ ways to fill in the 14 squares.
Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are adding when you should instead be multiplying.  Another way to think about it is that each of the $14$ matches has two outcomes: the top team wins or the bottom team wins.  So the total number of outcomes is $2^{14}$.